# Replace modelItem value of '0' with user friendly 'N'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 C# web application.

My Index View brings back results in a table, using @foreach.  Some of the fields are int and use 0 and 1 to designate No and Yes, respectively.

On the View, how do I display Y for 1 and N for 0 - to be more user friendly?  I have tried replace, but can't seem to get it to work without errors.

Regular Code:

```
<b>Wailist F-Lot:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.wait_E)
```

What I have tried (and failed):

```
<b>Wailist E-Lot:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.wait_E.Replace(item.current_lot, 0, "N"))
```

The error I get is "int does not contain a definition for 'Replace'.  Then what is the proper way to do this? or should it be handled in the model instead (and if so, how?)

Comment: you can use a ternary operation to set "N" when the value is  0, eg. `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.wait_E == 0 ? "N" : "Y"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in other to separate concerns, the best way is to add waitEstr string property to your model

```
public int wait_E  
{
get { return waitEstr  == "Y" ? 1: 0;}
set { waitEstr = value == 0 ? "N" : "Y" }
}

[NotMapped]
public string waitEstr { get; set;}
```

and view

```
<b>Wailist F-Lot:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.waitEstr)
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I expected.  Thank you